# How to change Spring AMQP protocol version from 0.9.1 to 1.0?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am a beginner to the Spring AMQP and I trying to understand what version of the AMQP protocol it uses, and how to change it.

AFAIK there are 2 variations of the AMQP protocol

- 0.9.1
- 1.0

**So how do I configure `Spring AMQP` to use 1.0 or 0.9.1 ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring AMQP only supports 0.9.1 and, specifically, RabbitMQ using that protocol version.